# Remove key from array if the element starts with certain value

Tags: php, arrays, unset

How can I remove element that starts with TOR example key [27].

```
Array
(
    [1] => memory_target
    [2] => vif_2_rx
    [3] => vif_2_tx
    [4] => memory
    [5] => vbd_xvda_read
    [6] => vbd_xvda_write
    [7] => vbd_xvdd_read
    [8] => vbd_xvdd_write
    [9] => vif_1_rx
    [10] => vif_1_tx
    [11] => vif_0_rx
    [12] => vif_0_tx
    [13] => cpu0
    [27] =>  TOR-SRV65
)
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
if(($key = array_search($del_val, $messages)) !== false) {
    unset($messages[$key]);
}
```

But haven't been able to get it to work!

Comment: Where are we with this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the elements out which have `TOR` at the start like this:

```
$messages = array_filter($messages, function($v){
    return !(substr(trim($v), 0, 3) === "TOR");
});
```

Case insensitive version:

```
$messages = array_filter($messages, function($v){
    return !(strtoupper(substr(trim($v), 0, 3)) === "TOR");
});
```

**EDIT:**

Even simpler with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-grep.php) (Remove the modifier `i` if you want it case sensitive):

```
$messages = preg_grep ("/[^\bTOR]/i", array_map("trim", $messages));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$array = array(
    'memory_target',
    'vif_2_rx',
    'TOR-SRV65'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strtolower(substr($value, 0, 3)) == 'tor') {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($array); // Output => Array ( [0] => memory_target [1] => vif_2_rx )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function to delete a key from array

```
function removeValueFromArray($array, $key, $value){
   foreach($array as $subKey => $subArray){
      if($subArray[$key] == $value){
      unset($array[$subKey]);
      }
   }
   return $array;
}
```

This function remove the key from array based on certain value and return final array